# Using AspNetUsers in windows forms application

Tags: asp.net, winforms, azure, user-input

I am trying to set up two projects. One mvc5 project and a windows forms project. I would like the user to register on the Mvc5 site and then be able to use the Username and Password in a windows forms login. I am storing the sql database in Azure. All I need to do is check the username and password but am not sure how to check the Hashed password saved in the AspNetUsers table as I dont know how MVC5 Encrypts the password when the user registers. Any pointers would be grateful, or advise if this is a sensible option to share users between projects?
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't encrypt the password. It one-way hashes it, and you would benefit from learning the difference.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Is it a sensible way of sharing username and password between two different systems? Is it easy to validate the hash in the windows forms project?